# C -- pointers to pointers VERSUS array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

In C, why can't I write:

```
char **expectedPINs01 = { "0", "5", "7", "8", "9" };
```

Cause I got:

> warning: initialization of ‘char **’ from incompatible pointer type
> ‘char *’

But it is possible to write:

```
char *expectedPINs01[] = { "0", "5", "7", "8", "9" };
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926129/char-vs-char-c-for-accessing-a-string-array

Comment: Adam, do you agree the 1st is a _pointer_ and the 2nd is an _array_?

Comment: In my view, there isn't really such a thing as an array in C. There are pointers, and there are different ways of allocating memory. [] is a shorthand in declarations for allocating space, and [] in expressions is a shorthand for pointer arithmetic. That's why for example `printf("%c\n", 1["hello"]);` compiles with no complaints even with `-Wall` and prints `e\n`. The number `1` is obviously not an "array", yet the [] shorthand happily does its work and produces 1 plus the address of the `h` to yield `e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `char **` you are getting enough space for one pointer. If you want this to behave like an array, you then have to `malloc` space sufficient for the size of the array and fill in the entries.

When you write `char *x[5]` you get enough space for 5 pointers.

When you use the initialization shorthand, you can omit the `5` because the compiler can see from your initializer that you want there to be space for 5 pointers, and it reserves enough space for them and then uses the initializer shorthand to fill them in for you.

Comment: "if you want this to behave like an array, you then have to malloc space ..." is one way. Others exists, yet the general idea is correct.